# Change regular switch to dimmer (US)

Tags: electrical, switch

My current regular switch has a black wire coming in to the switch and also going out on top and a purple wire coming in at the bottom.  There are two white wires spliced in the box but not connecting to the switch.

[image: existing switch]

My new switch has 4 wires as shown in the picture below

[image: new switch].

Should I connect black to black and red to purple and cap the others?

Comment: Good for you! You took pictures before you disconnected anything and also a picture of your new switch. You already got a good answer so I won't answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your existing setup:

- Black = Hot - "in" and "out to elsewhere"
- White = Neutral - not needed by a simple switch
- Purple = Switched Hot to the light
- Ground = Grounded from metal yoke of switch to metal box (which is likely grounded via metal conduit)

Your new switch is a bit of an unknown. **Brand and Model # would help.** Assuming it is "typical", a likely setup is:

- Black = Hot - connect it to all existing black wires
- Red = Switched Hot to the light - connect it to the purple wire
- Green = Ground - should not be needed, *but check instructions*. If the switch does not ground through the yoke then the green wire needs to be connected to the metal box using an appropriate screw
- Red with stripe = Additional wire for use as a 3-way switch. Cap this with a wire nut.

But the instructions, if this is a properly UL (or similar) listed device should make it all abundantly clear.

Checked instructions for OP's stated model (Lutron Diva Dimmer, DVWCL-153PH-IV). It does make it clear that ground *can* be capped if not used, so it is not critical to operation (I didn't think it would be, but there are some types of switches where ground can be used instead of neutral where that would be critical). However, it does *not* list "metal grounded box" as one of those situations. So ideally it should be grounded using a [ground screw like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-10-32-Ground-Screws-Green-10-Pack-G30002-PK10/310741863):
[image: ground screw]

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  The new switch is a Lutron Diva Dimmer, DVWCL-153PH-IV.  I just capped the ground and hope for the best